# Select certain columns from multiple rows

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to select all of the products that a user has purchased from my site, based on an order ID.

```
$orderid = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(orders_id) FROM orders") or die(mysql_error());
$orderid = mysql_fetch_row($orderid);

$productinfo = mysql_query("SELECT products_model, products_name, products_price, products_quantity FROM orders_products WHERE orders_id=" . $orderid[0]);
$productinfo = mysql_fetch_row($productinfo);

echo $productinfo[0] . "&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;" . $productinfo[1] . "&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;$" . $productinfo[2] . "&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;" . $productinfo[3] . "<br><br>";
```

This will pull one product from the database, but if the customer ordered 8 items, I would need this to loop until all of the products with an order ID of $orderid[0] have been selected. What would be the best way to go about this? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Consider using parametrized statements. See PDO. As it is, your code is vulnerable to SQL injections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things.

First, everyone here will tell you to look into using mysqli or pdo as an alternative to mysql_query, as they are much more secure, and actually easier to maintain and use.

See this article:

http://www.pontikis.net/blog/how-to-use-php-improved-mysqli-extension-and-why-you-should

Second, you could easily cut down your code by writing more efficient queries.

In this case you would want to use a SQL JOIN. (more about joins here http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/)

```
    SELECT products_model, products_name, products_price, products_quantity 
    FROM orders_products as products
    JOIN orders as orders on products.order_id = order.order_id
    WHERE products.order_id = {whatever order id you are trying to find}
```

This will give you all products that have been ordered for each order id.

And use a while loop to loop through all of your results that come out of your query